# BundleHost in Eclipse Luna (4.4)

Tags: eclipse

I had few checks for BundleHost in Eclipse Kepler. And it is an internal class (org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core), accessing bundledata. After upgrading Eclipse Luna, those classes are no more there including AbstractBundle and BundleData.  Any solution to get the same behavior as BundleHost/AbstractBundle?

Comment: What were you doing with this internal classes?

Comment: I was trying a sample plugin in Kepler to fetch bundledata (getBundle()) from an instance check whether it was bundlehost (extends AbstractBundle).But BundleData (not an internal class) also removed.

Comment: No proper migration info available too here.http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fporting%2F4.4%2Fincompatibilities.html

Comment: I think the `Bundle` interface has ways of getting most of the information that was in `BundleData`.